# Azure AD Signing Key Rollover

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

Azure sign in keys are rolling over on 15th August 2015. Some of my applications are not setup to cope with this automatically. I thought I had a solution that used the following function in Global.asax

```
protected void RefreshValidationSettings()
{
    string configPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\" + "Web.config";
    string metadataAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:FederationMetadataLocation"];
    ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry.WriteToConfig(metadataAddress, configPath);
}
```

This works in debug on my desktop and new keys are downloaded and written to my web.config.

When I upload the site to azure though I get a access denied

> Access to the path 'E:\sitesroot\0\Web.config' is denied.
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via , the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.

Weirdly though this was a suggestion given my [microsoft](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/active-directory-signing-key-rollover/#vs2012)

Comment: Can you try `WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null)` gets the root `web.config` file in the app as a `Configuration` object. `Configuration` object has `FilePath` property

Comment: Wouldn't this have the same problem as it is running under the same account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog post talks about this issue in detail. Maybe this could help you
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cie/2016/01/15/error-access-to-the-path-esitesroot0web-config-is-denied-when-storing-azure-ads-public-key-in-web-config-of-an-azure-cloud-services-application/

Comment: apologies should have mentioned i have tried this without success. I think the problem was the example uses the network service account. Azure appears to be using the ASP.NET account. I don't know though exactly what account I should put in the file it suggests creating. Any thoughts?

Comment: So i had made a mistake in the batch file and this works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The guidance you pointed out in the ["Web applications protecting resources and created with Visual Studio 2012" section of the Signing Key Documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/active-directory-signing-key-rollover/#vs2012) is only applicable to applications where you can modify the web.Config during run time.

Azure Web apps do not fall into this category. Beside the permissions issue you are facing, Azure Web apps make no guarantees of persistence of the underlying VM. This means that any run time changes to the web.Config can be undone at any point.

For the purpose of the August 15th rollover, you can run the application locally and simply update your applications' checked-in web.Config and Azure Web App's settings. Given that the metadata already has both the current key and the key that Azure AD will be rolling over to on the 15th, the resulting web.Config/settings will cover you for this specific event.

However, to properly support automatic rollover, your best bet is to migrate over your application to a newer stack, such as the Owin middleware.